# Setting Dropdownlist Value after dynamically generating options

Tags: jquery

I have this code to populate drop down list

```
        $("#btnEditInfo").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $("#ddlLocations").empty().append($("<option></option>").val("[-]").html("[-- Please Select Location --]")); ;
            populateLocationDDL();
            $("#ddlLocations").val(4);
```

Here is the populateLocationDDL

```
 function populateLocationDDL() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "adminc.aspx/GetLocationList",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (arten) {
                $.each(arten.d, function (val1, text) {
                    $("#ddlLocations").append($("<option></option>").val(text.LocationID).html(text.Name));
                });
                $("#ddlLocations").append($("<option></option>").val(arten.length + 1).html("Other..."));
            }
        });
    }
```

Now I want to be able to select the 4th option in the drop down list.. but its not working

Any help would be highly appreciated..
**Here is the fiddle**
jsfiddle.net/yYZ48
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself here
[Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830040/jquery-set-selected-select-option-doesnt-work-for-dynamically-added-option-but)

I moved my .val() code into ajax return callback and it worked like a charm

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "adminc.aspx/GetLocationList",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (arten) {
                $.each(arten.d, function (val1, text) {
                    $("#ddlLocations").append($("<option></option>").val(text.LocationID).html(text.Name));
                });
                $("#ddlLocations").append($("<option></option>").val(arten.length + 1).html("Other..."));

                // Select Location Based on USer ID
                $("#ddlLocations").val("3");
                PopulateLocationDetails();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#ddlLocations option:eq(3)").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

or this:

```
$("#ddlLocations").val($("#ddlLocations option:eq(3)").val());
```

Comment: i think it has something to do with $.map()... but am not sure where to exactly place that !

Comment: your jsfiddle have an error on ajax, I have update the code in the answer try now not in that jsfiddle please @AtharAnis